# How to source NAT on Ubuntu Server when accessing from wireguard interface to access server LAN environment

Tags: ubuntu, nat, wireguard

I have an Ubuntu Server 22.04 which I am accessing from wireguard interface 10.69.69.0/24, But I am having trouble accessing it's LAN environment on 10.0.0.0/24

I understand I need to do some source nat but I am not sure of the correct commands.

- From my laptop I can ping 10.69.69.0/24 & 10.0.0.50 but not anything else on 10.0.0.0/24
- From my server I can ping 10.69.69.0/24 and 10.0.0.0/24

I need to make the server when sending packets to 10.0.0.0/24 from 10.69.69.0/24 to change the source IP to 10.0.0.50 right?

Server:

- eno1: 10.0.0.50/24
- wg0:  10.69.69.10/24
- net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Laptop:

- wg0: 10.69.69.1/24

Thank you

Comment: In my opinion, NAT is when you don't have other choices. Here you have; everything's inside a RFC1918 network. Simply set up appropriate routes.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment. It seems like that devices on the lan 10.0.0.0/24 don't know where the network 10.69.69.0/24 resides. If the lan has another exit point like Internet, you can install a route for 10.69.69.0/24 in the gateway for the lan 10.0.0.0/24. Or as you said, you can source NAT.